# Controller Function to add current post to selected collection (has_many :through relation) with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through, has-many

I'm trying to create a Collections feature (same as Pinterest Boards) where designer (aka devise user) can create collections and assign posts to own collections. 1 post can belong to many collections, and 1 collection can have many posts. So I created the **has_many :through** relation via **collectivization table**.

Now I'm displaying user's collections in post show page with the code below

*posts/show.html.erb*

```
  <ul>
    <li>Select a collection to add:</li>
    <% @collections.each do |collection| %>
      <li><%= link_to collection.title, add_to_collection(@post) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

and assign the current post to the selected collection. So I started writing a function in post_controller.rb, but I could not manage to relate.

**↓ How should I write this add_to_collection function???**

*controllers/posts_controller.rb*

```
 def add_to_collection
     # I need to save current post to selected collection in here
 end
```

Thank you!

---

and I get this error

### [image]

---

*models/collectivizations.rb*

```
class Collectivization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to: post
    belongs_to: collection
end
```

---

*models/post.rb*

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history]

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :collections, through: :collectivizations

  ...
```

---

*models/collection.rb*

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :posts, through: :collectivizations
end
```

Comment: `Collectivization`? Just wow. You should use nested resources. And probably name `Collectivization` as `CollectionPost`.

Comment: *hint*: `add_to_collection` is not a path (see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)).

Comment: yeah I overdid with the naming :D but it was requiring naming ending with tion and some other specific thing. So I had to go with that. I will check nested resources, not sure how to save posts in nested. Thanks

Comment: What was requiring name ending with `tion`?

Comment: The relation model naming I was creating.

Comment: I've never heard of that before. Maybe a rails 5 thing? (I'm still on 4.)

Comment: Yeah, probably, btw when I forced to use a different name, it created multiple models ‍♂️. I love the simplicity of Ruby on Rails, but sometimes this specific file naming becomes really confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165916/discussion-between-jvillian-and-designer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, in `config/routes.rb`, you do:

```
resources :posts do 
  resources :collections, controller: :post_collections, except: [:create] do 
    post '/', to: :create 
  end
end
```

you'll get the following paths:

```
     post_collection POST   /posts/:post_id/collections/:collection_id(.:format)  post_collections#create
    post_collections GET    /posts/:post_id/collections(.:format)                 post_collections#index
 new_post_collection GET    /posts/:post_id/collections/new(.:format)             post_collections#new
edit_post_collection GET    /posts/:post_id/collections/:id/edit(.:format)        post_collections#edit
                     GET    /posts/:post_id/collections/:id(.:format)             post_collections#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:post_id/collections/:id(.:format)             post_collections#update
                     PUT    /posts/:post_id/collections/:id(.:format)             post_collections#update
                     DELETE /posts/:post_id/collections/:id(.:format)             post_collections#destroy
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                      posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)                                      posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                  posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                             posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                  posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                  posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                  posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                  posts#destroy
```

Then, you should create a `PostCollectionsController` that has a `create` action something like:

```
class PostCollectionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @post = Post.find_by(params[:post_id])
    @collection = Collection.find_by(params[:collection_id])
    @post.collections << @collection
    # render something or whatever
  end

end
```

Then, in `PostController.show`, you would do something like:

```
<ul>
  <li>Select a collection to add:</li>
  <% @collections.each do |collection| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to collection.title, post_collection_path(@post, collection), method: :post %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: ah I forgot the **routes** (of course) ‍♂️. So dont I need collectivizations table in your solution?

Comment: I had never seen anything like this line before. Googling to learn :D **@post.collections << @collection**

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a new row in the join table connecting the two.

```
def add_to_collection(post, collection)
     Collectivization.create!(post: post, collection: collection)
 end
```

And in your rails view pass the collection as a variable as well

Comment: hmm yeah it makes sense. How do I do the link_to for this? I keep getting "NoMethodError in Posts#show" error

Comment: Prefer `post.collections << collection`. Also, this doesn't address the `link_to` problem, which is the real issue.